# tinyMCE - Add style to <head> on getContent() method

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using timyMCE version 3 `{ majorVersion : '3', minorVersion : '5.4.1' }`. When I put `Content` in textarea, I got below data.

```
<html>
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Content </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

What should I do to change it to below output as I call `getContent()` method?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;" charset="UTF-8">
            <style>
                /** Specify a font named "MyFont",
                and specify the URL where it can be found: */
                @font-face {
                    font-family: "MyFont";
                    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/RSU_Regular.ttf');
                }
                body { font-family:"MyFont"}
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Content </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you help me please?